# change layout content from controller

Tags: layout, controller, yii, dynamic-linking

I am using Yii. I want to have a dynamic link on a layout. This dynamic link will be modified by controllers. Let's say that dynamic link uses a user's id given by controllers to perform a task.

I am thinking to use jQuery script to get user id returned by controllers then use the user id to modify a div that holds the dynamic link.

What do you think about this technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to dynamically change a link AFTER the page is rendered, with client-side JavaScript. But it makes more sense to dynamically render a different link the first time, during the server-size PHP rendering process. The controller generates the view, after all! I would get the user ID from the controller during the page request, pass the ID in to the view, and then build the link in the view dynamically on the initial page load.

If you are modifying a link in a *layout* (not a view), then the best thing to do is create a variable in the Controller, and set that variable with the view. Look at how Yii uses the $layout, $menu and $breadcrumbs variables to do this.

Assuming that the user is logged in and you want *their* ID, you can get the ID from the Yii::app() object as well, like so:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Edit user',array('user/edit','userId'=>Yii::app()->user->id)); ?>
```

But at that point, you can just request the user's ID in the controller, and don't need to build a link like this.

Assuming that you want a *different* user ID than the logged in user, pass that ID ($userId) from the controller into the view, and just do this (as Moyersy said):

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Edit user',array('user/edit','userId'=>$userId)); ?>
```

This will build the following link (where $userId = 99999999):

```
<a href="/user/edit?userId=99999999">Edit user</a>
```

So when the linked is clicked, in the actionEdit() you now have access to the user's ID via the GET variable $_GET['userId'].

NOW, if what you want to do *is* change an already created link, then you would need to use jQuery. But you will need to explain in more detail why you are doing this and what is triggering the link change (a dropdown menu?).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I can't understand what you are trying to do.  Specifically I don't understand what a dynamic link is.

Edit:

```
<? echo CHtml::link('Edit user',array('user/edit','userId'=>$userId)); ?>
```

Comment: What I mean by 'dynamic link' is a link on a layout that calls to a controller's action. And this link takes a user's id and pass it to the controller's action. So with different user this link will pass a different user id to a controller.

The question is how to dynamically modify the link?
If the user id = 3, the link will call like this "?r=controller_name\action&userid=3"